# How can I copy an empty folder to an output directory when running MS unit testing framework?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am trying to test a method that throws an exception when encountering an empty directory. The problem is that when I build the project and run the test, the empty directory doesn't get copied over UNLESS there is a file in the directory. I placed a "dummy file" in the directory and sure enough, the directory was visible. In VS, when you add a folder to a project, there are no "properties" associated with it so I can't specify that I want it copied to the output directory.

So, How can I copy an empty folder to an output directory when running MS unit testing framework?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us help you, please show the code you've experimented with.

Comment: After further digging around in Visual Studio, I found a section "Setup and Cleanup scripts" under Test > Edit test settings > local test settings.

I pretty much wrote a simple batch script to create the empty folder and had it run right before the test run was performed.